# MFC Rich Edit Control 2.0 receiving click event

Tags: c++, checkbox, visual-studio-2015, mfc, cricheditctrl

I was hoping someone out there would help me with my predicament I ran into. Essentially I have a Checkbox and a RichEditControl next to each other. I want to be able to know when a user has clicked on my RichEditControl so i can send a message to my checkbox to flag it on and off.

At first i tried to overlay my checkbox with empty text to act as a "blank" background for my RichEditControl so i wouldn't have to worry about sending messages left and right. No matter what i tried the "blank" background would overlap the RichEditControl text and leave it completely blank.

I searched on here for some help and i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472798/how-do-i-make-mfc-checkbox-read-only-but-keep-text-enabled) which is exactly what I ran into. I understand what he is saying but don't have the knowledge to implement what they said.

Right now I'm playing around with EN_LINK to attempt to capture a message so i can tell my checkbox to flag itself.

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(TempInit, CDialog)
ON_NOTIFY(EN_LINK, IDC_TempInitMsg, &TempInit::OnEnLinkTempinitmsg)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void TempInit::OnEnLinkTempinitmsg(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
ENLINK *pEnLink = reinterpret_cast<ENLINK *>(pNMHDR);
// TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    radioClicked = !radioClicked;
    if (radioClicked == true)
    {
        GetParent()->SendMessage(WM_MYRADIOCLICKED, CHECKENABLED, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        GetParent()->SendMessage(WM_MYRADIOCLICKED, CHECKDISABLED, 0);
    }
}
*pResult = 0;
}
```

I'm sorry in advance if this is totally the wrong way to go about this. I've been googling for a few hours and have come empty handed. If anyone has any other method please help me if possible. I can post more code if what i have above isn't enough.

Comment: will getfocus and killfocus message solve your problem?

Comment: That's a happy mixture of a problem you are trying to solve, your proposed solution, and the problems that are the result of your solution. It's hard to tell, which one is which. At first I thought your first paragraph was your actual problem, but then you posted a link to another Q&A, that (presumably) is dealing with a completely different issue. What are you ultimately trying to accomplish?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! the link i provided was similar but not the same question is what i should of said. My plan is to be able to click on a RichEditControl text and tell my checkbox to flag itself on and off. I tried having the checkbox contain empty text and "hide" it under the RichEditControl text but as soon as the user hovers over the "hidden and empty" field it overlaps the text thus leaving it blank

Comment: @ChristianAbella
I actually tried to use that on the checkbox already and i couldn't get anything definitive to work. Although i can try again, maybe i need to play around with the properties a bit more

Comment: Do you just want to check the checkbox when Rich Edit Ctrl is clicked and uncheck the checkbox when Rich Edit Ctrl is out of focus? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @ChristianAbella
I want the user to be able to click on the Rich Edit Ctrl to check or uncheck the checkbox - which i believe is what you already said

Answer (score 0):

Steven,

One way to go about this would be to handle the `EN_MSGFILTER` notification from the rich edit control. I can't provide you any code to show you how to do this off hand but [here's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hc7fy921.aspx) the documentation for the Notification messages from that the Rich edit control generates. Simply handle it the same way your doing with your radio button.

Comment: Hi John,

I have been reading that and usually they post an "example" so i can start with something but i just don't understand how to implement what they are saying. I will try to post what i have tried in a few hours so maybe you can point me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

This will check the check box when the Rich Edit Ctrl has the focus and untick
it when it losses the focus.

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(TempInit, CDialogEx)
  ON_EN_SETFOCUS(IDC_RICHEDIT21, &TempInit::OnEnSetfocusRichedit21)
  ON_EN_KILLFOCUS(IDC_RICHEDIT21, &TempInit::OnEnKillfocusRichedit21)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void CMFCApplication1Dlg::OnEnSetfocusRichedit21()
{
  CButton* pCheckBox = (CButton*)GetDlgItem(IDC_CHECK1);
  pCheckBox->SetCheck(1);
}

void CMFCApplication1Dlg::OnEnKillfocusRichedit21()
{
  CButton* pCheckBox = (CButton*)GetDlgItem(IDC_CHECK1);
  pCheckBox->SetCheck(0);
}
```